# How to disabling of back button do not spoil work of refresh button in php application?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I set my *BACK* button on a page (PHP) which redirects to a new page when it is clicked using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
          var hashLocation = location.hash;
          var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
          var hashName = hashSplit[1];

          if (hashName !== '') {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            if (hash === '') {
                window.location='KorisnikNeMozeUnazad.html';
                return false;
            }
          }
        });

        window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
      }

    });
</script>
```

It works but the *REFRESH* button on same page doesn't work using the above script. When it is clicked, the application just closes.

Is there any way to get the *REFRESH* button to work so it will refresh the content of my page but to also have the *BACK* button still redirect to the page I want?

Comment: Can you show the button html?

Comment: No, no I didn`t make these buttons by myself, those are normal buttons of my browser...Those pages are in www folder on my wamp server and I open them using google chrome. I just changed normal function of back button with this code above and after that normal function of refresh button doesn`t work...

Comment: O, I gotcha you are changing the normal functions of the browser buttons.

Comment: Exactly! Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle for this problem? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not undersatnd in jsfiddle...Can you help me about that?